# Firebase "MD5" & BloddyCrytpo's dont match

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to do a check to see if the user has a local file. If the user does, I get [bloodycrypto](https://github.com/blooddy/blooddy_crypto) to make a md5 out of it. Then I compare the two values. One from the firebase file's metadata and the other from the byte array of the file digested. They never match. Does Firebase do something different when trying to generate the md5 of a file I upload?

```
    private function handleMetaSuccess(e:StorageReferenceEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Meta succes for reference:" + this.name);
        storageMetaData = e.metadata;
        trace("reading file.");
        fileBA = new ByteArray();
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(Definitions.CACHE_DIRECTORY.resolvePath(name + ".jpg"), FileMode.READ)
            fs.readBytes(fileBA);
            fs.close();

            var byteHash:String = MD5.hashBytes(fileBA)

            trace("Local hash = " + byteHash); //93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71
            trace("Network hash = " + storageMetaData.md5Hash); //bo7XPotC+T5wmAcpagnXBw==
            if (byteHash != storageMetaData.md5Hash)
            {
                trace("Not equal. Getting file."); //Always happens
                getFile();
            }
            else
            {
                loadFile();
            }
    }
```

Upon closer inspetion (thanks to Organis) firebase doesn't return a proper MD5. What is it? In my storage consol I don't see an md5 property, so is this autogenerated? The files were uploaded through [my rest API](https://github.com/sfxworks/FirebaseREST/blob/master/src/net/sfxworks/firebaseREST/Storage.as) based off [phantom's](https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3) guide.

Update: Following Organis' comment about the way [Firebase handle's MD5s](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.FullMetadata#md5Hash)

```
            var byteHash:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            byteHash.writeUTFBytes(MD5.hashBytes(fileBA));

            var byteHashWithLength:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            byteHashWithLength.writeUTF(MD5.hashBytes(fileBA));

            trace("Bytehash with length = " + Base64.encode(byteHashWithLength)); //ACAyMTMzYTdmYjczYTEzZDQ3ZDkzMTEyY2I1OWQyYTBmMg==
            trace("Plain = " + Base64.encode(byteHash)); //OTNiODg1YWRmZTBkYTA4OWNkZjYzNDkwNGZkNTlmNzE=
            trace("Storage md5 = " + storageMetaData.md5Hash);  //UsoNl5sL1+aLiAhTOTBXyQ==
```

Trying to take the md5 I get and turn it into base64 results in consistent mismatching results. Is there an argument I am missing or applying incorrectly when I try to decode everything?

Comment: **bo7XPotC+T5wmAcpagnXBw==** is not a valid MD5 hash. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 *The 128-bit (16-byte) MD5 hashes (also termed message digests) are typically represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits.*

Comment: Hmm. What is it then? It should be a hash. I am using distriq's Firebase Storage to get the md5 hash. Through the event, using the getter storageMetaData.md5Hash is the equiv to the android's version https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties

Comment: Found another thread on firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380078/firebase-storage-getmetadata-issue It seems its MD5 implementation is different. Also, found another page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.FullMetadata *A Base64-encoded MD5 hash of the object being uploaded.* Might be that it is indeed Base64(MD5(...)) instead of just MD5.

Comment: @quantomworks it is a **Base64** encoding of the bytes (in hex) : `6E 8E D7 3E 8B 42 F9 3E 70 98 07 29 6A 09 D7 07` if they mean anything to you. You know it's Base64 cos it ends with `==` however the `Local hash` seems to be hex values so you are comparing text (B64) against integers (Hex)

Comment: @VC.One How would I go about comparing the two? I tried `var decodedHash:ByteArray = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash);` and then a readUTFBytes of its length but I got a bad string.

Comment: @quantomworks I think you should rather **Base64.encode(byteHash)** and see if there any resemblance.

Comment: @Organis I tried that and updated the question. It doesn't match :(

Comment: @quantomworks So far I figured that you need to **Base64.encode** 16 bytes (which is MD5 hash) in order to produce a string of length 24, just like your firebase provides.

Comment: I know and I definitely appreciate it. I am wondering if there is something I am missing in my steps. The only thing I see is an extra arg I can pass with the Base64 function. I wonder if google adds something in or considers the file without the metadata when generating the md5...which would make sense now that I saw it. But if it includes other properties or doesn't send any of them in the download..the steps to solve the problem could become like finding the exact number of 0s for a block in a blockchain..

Comment: @quantomworks In your original top code you need something like : `var storageHash:String = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash);` to get MD5 (hex) digits represented as a **String** object. Now you can compare the 2 strings `byteHash` vs `storageHash`... All I know is your `byteHash = "93 B8 85 AD FE 0D A0 89 CD F6 34 90 4F D5 9F 71"` but then your `storageHash = "6E 8E D7 3E 8B 42 F9 3E 70 98 07 29 6A 09 D7 07"`. Don't know why...

Comment: @VC.One storageMetaData.md5hash is returned as a String and not a bytearray. I attempted to convert that and run it but I get a bad string with some bad characters.

Comment: @quantomworks yes you get a (B64) string, so you decode that to see what it represents which gives another string of now hex values (like a printed bytearray). That final string result can be compared with `byteHash`since `var byteHash:String = MD5.hashBytes(fileBA)` also makes a string. PS; you get bad chars cos of `writeUTFBytes`. To simplify : You're mapping hex values (max 255 decimal) against UTF text (max 26 A-Z letters). Now imagine any decimal/hex value higher than 26 can potentially give you unreadable char. That hex `6E` == decimal `110` what letter is that?

Comment: @VC.One I'm not following your answer. In my previous comment, I was referencing me 1. decoding the received md5hash into a ByteArray and 2. reading the decoded ByteArray into a string using readUTFBytes (resulting in RIÊÈÿ滥ǖu*Õ) which, according to your comment, I can think is due to me giving it a higher value than it can manage. So then.. I take this 'string' and decode it again to get the final result? At first, it sounded like I was to encode and decode. Is this how Base64s work? And why are the values you compared not equal? I have two identical files...

Comment: @quantomworks I'm telling you that your top code is fine. No need for UTF or extra bytearrays. Just decode that `storageMetaData.md5hash` from base64 format to normal text. Try`var storageHash:String = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash);` before your `IF` statement and what is the `trace` result of `storageHash`? It should be String made up of hex values (you'll know its hex cos the chars are made of 0-9 and letters A-F **only**, any higher letters "G" onwards means it's not valid hex & therefore is not valid MD5 hash). Your `byteHash` is already a string made of hex values.

Comment: PS: can you be sure that Firebase is not modifying the "copied" (or recreated) bytes when you upload? For example if it adds metadata bytes then the final hash would be different compared to local file. Do you have a link for image as directly saved fom Firebase server?

Comment: Honestly, I should make a separate file containing all these base64 hashes along with the file location instead of loading each one into memory synchronously since I'm not worried about any consequence of the user altering the file. Though I will still try to answer this on my next test by applying your set. @VC.One Base64.decode returns a ByteArray, so I would do something like `var storageHash:String = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash).toString()` to follow your example right? Or would that mess something up when converting it?

Comment: storageHash, following that method, results in the same when I tried the reverse in my comment using readUTFBytes. Example trace: /äîúۊðS®

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...So I would do something like
>
> ```
> var storageHash:String = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash).toString();
> ```
>
> to follow your example right?

Try this code below to get your `storageMetaData.md5Hash` correctly decoded from Base64 :

Let me know result of `trace("storage hash : " + storageHash);` to check if you're getting an (expected) sequence of 32 hex values.

```
private function handleMetaSuccess(e:StorageReferenceEvent):void 
{
    trace("Meta succes for reference:" + this.name);
    storageMetaData = e.metadata;
    trace("reading file.");
    fileBA = new ByteArray();
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(Definitions.CACHE_DIRECTORY.resolvePath(name + ".jpg"), FileMode.READ)
    fs.readBytes(fileBA);
    fs.close();

    var byteHash:String = MD5.hashBytes(fileBA); //Local hash

    var ba_storageHash:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    ba_storageHash = Base64.decode(storageMetaData.md5Hash); //update ByteArray
    var storageHash:String = bytesToHexString(ba_storageHash); //Hex values of bytes shown as String


    trace("Network hash : " + storageMetaData.md5Hash); //bo7XPotC+T5wmAcpagnXBw==
    trace("Local hash   : " + byteHash); //93b885adfe0da089cdf634904fd59f71
    trace("storage hash : " + storageHash); //what is result??

    if (byteHash != storageHash)
    {
        trace("Not equal. Getting file."); //Always happens
        getFile();
    }
    else
    {
        loadFile();
    }
}

// # Byte values (Hex) shown as (returned) String type
private function bytesToHexString(input:ByteArray) : String
{
    var strOut:String = ""; var strRead:String = "";
    input.position = 0;
    var intBASize:uint = input.length;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < intBASize; i++)
    {
        strRead = input.readUnsignedByte().toString(16); 

        if(strRead.length < 2) { strRead = "0" + strRead; } //# do padding
        strOut += strRead ;     
    }

    return strOut.toLowerCase(); //strOut.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: This returns matching hashes for files that I have already saved. Thanks.